# How can I onSubmit redirect the results of an api call to another page?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I want the results of an api call to be shown on an '/events' page. I've tried using Redirect from react-router-dom but this only redirects the page.

I have tried looking at this answer

[How can I on Submit my Form redirect the Results to another Page in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55668145/how-can-i-on-submit-my-form-redirect-the-results-to-another-page-in-react)

But am unsure how this could apply to my code. If I use this.props.history.push('/events') I get an error message saying it doesn't recognize .push.

Would be grateful if someone can put me on the right course.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Form, FormControl, Button}  from 'react-bootstrap';
import './style.css';


class SearchField extends Component {

    state = {
        search: ""
    };


    handleChange = (event) => {
        const {name, value} = event.target;
        this.setState({[name]: value.toLowerCase()});
    };


    apiCall = () =>{

        const corsAnywhere = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
        const ticketmasterURL = "https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events/?keyword=";
        const searchKey = process.env.REACT_APP_TM_KEY;
        const term = this.state.search.split(" ").join("+");


        axios.get(corsAnywhere + ticketmasterURL + term + "&apikey=" + searchKey)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data._embedded.events);
            this.history.push("/events");
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };


    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.apiCall();
    };


    render(){
        return (
            <div className="search-container">
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <FormControl 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Search" 
                            name="search"
                            value={this.state.search} 
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                        <div className="btn-container">
                            <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
                        </div>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form>
            </div>
        )
    }

}


export default SearchField;
```

Comment: You can share that data in a Context API provider and access in the desired component

Comment: Could you clarify how that would work? I read the documents and it seems Context API is more for styling?

Comment: It's just an example, you can use it to share data among your components like Redux (it uses Context API behind the scenes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `this.props.history.push('/events')`, you are getting error.

Because to work with `history` object you need to wrap your component using [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) HOC.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class SearchField extends Component { ... }

export default withRouter(SearchField)
```

Now you can use `history` object to sent data,

```
axios.get(corsAnywhere + ticketmasterURL + term + "&apikey=" + searchKey)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data._embedded.events);

      this.props.history.push({
        pathname: '/events',
        state: { events_data: JSON.stringify(res.data._embedded.events) }
      })

    })
```

In `events` component you can access the data like,

```
render(){
    const events_data = JSON.parse(this.props.location.state.events_data)
    console.log(events_data)

    return( ... )
}
```

---

You can make use of [`Redirect`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md#to-object) from `react-router-dom` package to send data as well.

```
axios.get(corsAnywhere + ticketmasterURL + term + "&apikey=" + searchKey)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data._embedded.events);

      <Redirect 
         to={{
            pathname: '/events',
            state: { events_data: JSON.stringify(res.data._embedded.events) }
         }}
      />
    })
```

In `events` component you can access the data like,

```
render(){
    const events_data = JSON.parse(this.props.location.state.events_data)
    console.log(events_data)

    return( ... )
}
```

Comment: WithRouter worked for me. Big thanks. For Redirect, I had problems with rendering the events page.

Comment: I am having problems with showing the results of the page. After adding those two lines

    const events_data = JSON.parse(this.props.location.state.events_data)
    console.log(events_data)

I get

TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Would you know why this might be?

Comment: I think you are not getting API response.

Comment: I can see the api response on the search page if I console log it. And when I look at the history prop, it shows the state. It's when I console.log this.props in the events page, I get undefined.

Comment: Did you wrap your events component using `withRouter`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I quite new to react: would that be to wrap it like this? export default withRouter(EventListing)?

Comment: I sort of have it working. I had to pull out location, match, and history and assign it to a variable. It wouldn't just work as this.props.location.state.